# VBA or Excel Function to Count Non-Zeros in a Comma-separated String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell(s) that contains the following: [90,90,90,0,90].

I want only to count the non-zero numerals before or after a comma.

So, in the above example, the answer is 4, as "90" appears 4 times.

If the cell contained [180,180,0,0,0,0,0,0,90], the answer would be 3.

Is there VBA or Excel function (played with LEN, SUBSTITUTE, TRIM, etc. without luck) to accomplish this?

Thank you,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

If your data is as strict as shown:

- does not have spaces between commans
- does not have non-zero numbers with leading zeroes, e.g. `0180`

then the following very inefficient formula will work:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))) + 1 - (
   (LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",0",",")))
  +(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[0,","[,")))
  +(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",0]",",]")))
)
```

Otherwise you should probably use VBA:

```
Public Function CountNonZero(ByVal s As String) As Long
  Dim arr() As String
  arr = Split(Mid$(Trim$(s), 2, Len(s) - 2), ",")

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Trim$(arr(i)) <> "0" Then CountNonZero = CountNonZero + 1
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll build the Excel formula step by step, so you can see the approach.

The plan is to calculate the length of a string that doesn't include the zero elements and compare that to the length of the original string.

The first step is to Substitute any zero elements with empty strings. But we can't just eliminate all zeros because there can be zeros in non-zero entries (e.g., "100"). So we need to identify list entries.

Here I assume a couple things:

1. There will be no spaces (blanks) between the commas and the list items.
2. If a list item begins with a zero, then the item is zero. In other words, leading zeros (like 012) are NOT allowed.

We can make adjustments if either of these assumptions is wrong. But it's simpler if we can make these assumptions, and they're consistent with your examples.

So, we can remove zero items by Substituting ",0" with ",". But we hit a snag. Substituting ",0" won't find a 0 if it's the first item. So, let's add a comma before the first element of the list of numbers. That lets us use ",0" for the substitute.

```
=Substitute(ref, "[", "[,")
```

I'm using 'ref' to be the cell address where the string is located.

Now, let's add the Substitute to get rid of the 0 items from the list:

```
=Substitute(Substitute(ref, "[", "[,"), ",0", ",")
```

Note that we're using the results of the first (inner) Substitute as the input to the second (outer) Substitute.

Now, find the number of zero items that were removed, by comparing the length of the original string to the length of the calculated string:

```
=Len(ref) - Len(Substitute(Substitute(ref, "[", "[,"), ",0", ",")) + 1
```

We need to add one at the end of the formula because we made our calculated string one character longer when we added the comma before the first item in the list.

Before you copy the formula into Excel, remember to change 'ref' to the actual cell reference. It occurs in two places in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The **array-formula** below will do what you want.

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

```
=SUM(--IFERROR(-TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))<>0,0))
```

where `seq_99` is a Named Formula that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

- `SUBSTITUTE` replaces each comma with 99 spaces
- The `MID` function, with a the `seq_99` formula for the `start_number` returns an array of values starting at {1,99,198,297,...}` which will be each of the values in the string.
- `TRIM` removes the extra spaces from each array element
- `-` converts the string representation of the number to a numeric value

  - This will return an error for the null-strings in the array
- We then test each element in the array to see that it is not a zero.

  - This will return an array of `{TRUE,FALSE,#VALUE!,...}
  - `IFERROR` will convert the errors to zero's
- Sum will then add all the `TRUE` values (`TRUE` = +1 in Excel)

For a VBA method:

```
Option Explicit
Function nonZero(s As String) As Long
    Dim v, w
    Dim l As Long
v = Split(s, ",")
For Each w In v
    If Val(w) <> 0 Then l = l + 1
Next w
nonZero = l
End Function
```

**EDIT**
I assumed that the brackets `[…]` you show were not actually in the cell, but showed the cell boundaries.  If they might or might not actually be in the cell, you should modify the above formula to:

```
=SUM(--IFERROR(-TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[",""),"]",""),",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))<>0,0))
```

or the User Defined Function to:

```
Option Explicit
Function nonZero(s As String) As Long
    Dim v, w
    Dim l As Long
    Dim str As String
str = Replace(s, "[", "")
str = Replace(str, "]", "")

v = Split(str, ",")
For Each w In v
    If Val(w) <> 0 Then l = l + 1
Next w
nonZero = l
End Function
```

Comment: If `seq_99` is in a separate cell, it always returns 1 and the main formula always returns 0. If `seq_99` is a part of the original formula, then it fails to count non-zero values in the beginning and in the end of the list, returning 1 for `[180,180,0,0,0,0,0,0,90]` (misses the first 180 and the last 90) and 2 for `[90,90,90,0,90]` (misses the first and last 90).

Comment: @GSerg `seq_99` is a named formula. (Or you could replace it in the formula.) It definitely should **NOT** be placed in a separate cell and referred to by cell reference.

Comment: @GSerg look at the Formula tab to define it.

Comment: It still misses the first and last elements.

Comment: @GSerg Then there may be something different about your data.  I assumed that the `[]` were not really part of the string, but were cell boundary markers.  If they are part of the string, they would need to be removed first -- a simple modification.

Answer (score -1):

obviously my original answer was not helping..

here's my updated answer:

```
Public Function NonZero(str As String) As Integer

    NonZero = 0
    str = Replace(Replace(Replace(str, " ", ""), "[", ""), "]", "") ' get rid of bracket & space, or whatever...


    Dim x As Integer
    Do While Len(str) > 0

        x = InStr(1, str, ",")
        If x = 1 Then       'start with ","
            str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
            x = InStr(1, str, ",")
        End If

        If x > 0 Then
            If Val(Left(str, x - 1)) <> 0 Then
                NonZero = NonZero + 1
            End If
            str = Right(str, Len(str) - x)
        Else
            If Val(str) <> 0 Then
                NonZero = NonZero + 1

            End If
            str = ""
        End If
    Loop

End Function
```

test result:
[image]